# How can I make this script to run on Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("text1").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Code html:

```
 <div class="div1">
    <p class="text1">text to appear when the user puts the mouse over</p>
</div>
```

I want to apply this script to my website in Wordpress.

I put this code in functions.php

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_echipa' );
function script_echipa() 

{ wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/echipa.js', array('jquery'), null, true );

}
```

It is a very simple script that works smoothly on local Wordpress but we did not implement it.

Is something wrong?

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a . before the selector for class text1 --> "text1"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text1").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check this out: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/151777/how-to-correctly-add-javascript-in-functions-php

Comment: I thought of copy pasting the solution from there but I think it's better if you go through the full answer rather than a copy paste code snippet

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses noconflict so you have to wrap your scripts in `jQuery(function($) {});` in order to be able to use the dollar sign. Like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".text1").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The script (echipa.js) doesn't seem to be included on http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=10

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/w1faxu.png I put this picture to see that the script is added